# Displaying page numbers

Tags: c#, pagination, page-numbering

I'd like to mimic how this paging works:

[image]

Notice how the current page will always show two pages on either side? This seems like it would be a lot of conditional code when you factor in the case that you may be on page 4 and there is no gap between 1 and 3 or if you are on page 1 it will show more than two numbers to the right.

Can somebody get me off to the right start?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's sample output from console program with logic you are looking for:

Program.exe 1

1 2 3...100

Program.exe 2

1 2 3 4...100

Program.exe 5

1...3 4 5 6 7...100

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // usage program.exe page#
        // page# between 1 and 100
        int minPage = 1;
        int maxPage = 100;
        int currentPage = int.Parse(args[0]);

        // output nice pagination
        // always have a group of 5

        int minRange = Math.Max(minPage, currentPage-2);
        int maxRange = Math.Min(maxPage, currentPage+2);

        if (minRange != minPage)
        {
            Console.Write(minPage);
            Console.Write("...");
        }

        for (int i = minRange; i <= maxRange; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i);
            if (i != maxRange) Console.Write(" ");
        }

        if (maxRange != maxPage)
        {
            Console.Write("...");
            Console.Write(maxPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your usage of Math.Max/Min is very clever.

Comment: This is good, really good. However just wanted to note that if you're on page 4 you will have a minrange of 2 and thus will render `1...2 3 4` etc. There needs to be another conditional line in the block of `minRange != minPage` just above the elipses which is `if(minRange-1 != minPage)`

Answer (score 0):

```
int n = 34 //max page
int current = 5 //current page

if(current > 1)
     //Dislpay 'prev'

if (current < 5){
    for(int i=1; i<current; ++i)
        //Display i
}
else {
    //Display 1 followed by ...
    for(int i=current-2; i<current; ++i)
        //Display i
}

//Display current in red

if (current > n-4) {
    for(int i = current+1; i<=n; ++i)
        //Display i
}
else {
    for(int i=current+1; i<current+3; ++i)
        //Display i
    //Display ... folowed by n
}

if (current < n)
    //Display 'next'
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You know the first page
2. You know the last page
3. You know the current page

So

- If there are more than 2 pages between first & current, show '...' then two pages closest to current
- else show all pages between first and current
- repeat for last